# What are the IBUs (bitterness units) of common lagers? Also, what are hop contents?

Tags: hops, lager

I would be interested to know these two things:

(1): What are the ratings in IBU of common lagers: e.g. Stella, Kronenbourg, Fosters, Becks, Heineken, San Miguel, Corona? Are there major differences?

(2): Same question RE: Hoppyness/Hop content.

E.g. I like Stella and not Becks. Then my friend told me that's because Stella is more bitter. However I have no way of knowing for sure... hence the question.

I like IPAs and I hate stouts. However the differences between lagers is difficult to perceive for me.

Comment: You will never know the exact IBU of common lagers because that is "secret" information. You can guess approximately based on style guidelines. Same for the hops...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If 'differences between lagers' is difficult to perceive then why care about IBU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of ibu's:

- Stella: 30
- Kronenbourg 1664: 20
- Corona: 10
- Fosters: 12
- Becks: 20
- Heineken: 23
- San Miguel: 12

The difference in IBU seems to come from the type of beer, Heineken en Becks are quite similar european lagers with the same ingredients(barly, yeast water and hops) while Corona uses corn and rice with much les hops.

Grohlier already gave a good answer for the second question.

Comment: It's interesting to see how much difference there is between common lagers. Never would have guessed.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a compiled list of common-marketplace lagers is probably not going to happen unless someone has made a specific list [like this](http://gearpatrol.com/2016/04/13/best-american-lagers/).

Generally, you would just search "*SPECIFIC BEER* IBU" and either the result or website where you can find the result would populate. You can also look at [homebrewer clone-recipe sites like this](http://www.brewersfriend.com/search/) that give you the IBUs and recipes for clones of your favorite beers.

There are, however, sites [like this](http://www.brewersfriend.com/2009/01/24/beer-styles-ibu-chart-graph-bitterness-range/) that have BJCP average IBU ranges for varying styles of beer.

For proprietary reasons, you will never know the exact make-up of hops/hop ratios in beers unless the [company shares that information with their imbibers.](https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/how-to-brew/craft-breweries-share-homebrew-clone-recipes/)

If you have a good palate and understanding of what [kinds of hops](http://appellationbeer.com/blog/hop-union-hop-aroma-wheel/) yield what [kinds of flavors](https://byo.com/resources/hops), you might be able to pick them out.

Comment: I just realized "kinds of hops...kinds of flavors" seem like a hop-link and hop-flavor link. They are, in fact, the same concept... One is a wheel and the other is an Excel-style list.